# phpmyadmin export function - compression

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I tried to read the phpmyadmin documentation, but there is no reference about how the export function works!
Is it using mysqldump?

My problem is that I have a 1gb+ dB, which compressed is only 10 MB.

Will phpmyadmin download the whole data and then compress it locally or will it let the server do the compression and give me only the resulting gzipped file?

Ps: same question applies during the upload, will phpmyadmin upload a compressed file to the server and let the server handle it or will it decompress it first?

Answer (score 3):

In the "output" section on the "export" page you can choose "compression" (none,zipped,gzipped)

*.zip and *.gzip uploads will be automatically uncompressed

> File may be compressed (gzip) or uncompressed. A compressed file's name must end in .[format].[compression]. Example: .sql.zip

The only potential issue is that default max size is 128MB (I believe) so you may have to edit that in the settings

Comment: yes, I know how to set it.. but my question was: Will phpmyadmin download the whole data and then compress it locally or will it let the server do the compression and give me only the resulting gzipped file?

Comment: how could it compress it locally??? if will make the zip/gzip on the server and you'll download only that - there would be a little point of compression after the download

Comment: your answer makes sense, but I don't understand why by looking at my network connection transfer I can see that the full data is being streamed to my pc even if the gzip size is way smaller!

Comment: it is possible that your server doesn't support zip/gzip (they are not installed or php cannot execute them) in which case the app just sends uncompressed data

Comment: the strange thing is that I DO get a gzip, but the data transfer equals the uncompressed file size! I have to do additional testing because this makes no sense..

Comment: i believe that is because the script tries to compress the data but the compressor (gzip) is not available so it sends the data uncompressed (but doesn't bother to change the extension of the download file)